# If exists ... else clause in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a db and need to extract some data from it for use in a python script. I'm new to sql and just know the basics.
This is what I want to do:

```
if exists (
select date, sum(amount) 
from transactions 
where category = 'Food' 
group by date
) 
else 
select date, 0
```

For all dates present in `transaction` table, I want to get *date*, *sum(amount)* for category *Food*. If there are no transactions with category *Food* I want to get *date*, *0* (since *sum(amount)* of *Food* that day is 0).

The code I currently have is

```
select date, sum(amount) 
from transactions 
where category = 'Food' 
group by date
```

but it doesn't contain the *date*, *0* rows for dates which don't have any *Food* transactions.

How should I rewrite this to make it work?

**I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746306/sqlite-if-exists-clause) question, but the answer there is exclusive to boolean data, doesn't provide enough details and can't be generalized.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't make it clear for which dates you want to get `0`: you can't just list all dates which aren't present in your data, there is an infinite number of them! However, I guess that you meant to get `date, 0` for those dates where there *are* transactions, but none of them have category `'Food'`. In this case you can do this:

```
select date, sum(case when category = 'Food' then amount else 0 end)
from transactions
group by date
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll reword the question, but you assumed right and your answer is exactly what I was looking for. I haven't come across the `case` keyword before, but like I said, I'm new to sql and have much to learn. Thank you for your time

Comment: I'm not a native english speaker and can't see a way to word it better. Can you reword the question for me? Thanks again