# IF ELSE workaround in Sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to do a simple upsert query in SQL. This query works in SQL Server

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE SomeId = @SomeId AND SomeOtherId = @SomeOtherId))
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TableName 
        SET "SomeColumn" = @SomeValue 
        WHERE SomeId = @SomeId AND SomeOtherId = @SomeOtherId;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TableName VALUES (@SomeId, @SomeOtherId, @SomeValue);
    END
```

However, our Unit tests run on Sqlite and in general we want to write vanilla SQL, so this IF ELSE won't work.
I was trying to pull it off with CASE WHEN but I can't get it right. Can somebody post a working Sqlite query?

Thanks in advance, 
Marko

Comment: Possible duplicate... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746306/sqlite-if-exists-clause

Comment: That didn't quite helped me since I needed query to be executed depending on EXISTS not just value return, but thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is (or you can create) a unique constraint for the combination of the columns `SomeId` and `SomeOtherId`, then you might use [`UPSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableName(SomeId, SomeOtherId, SomeColumn)
VALUES(@SomeId, @SomeOtherId, @SomeValue)
ON CONFLICT(SomeId, SomeOtherId) DO 
UPDATE SET SomeColumn = @SomeValue;
```

If not then use 2 statements:

```
UPDATE TableName 
SET SomeColumn = @SomeValue 
WHERE SomeId = @SomeId AND SomeOtherId = @SomeOtherId;

INSERT INTO TableName (SomeId, SomeOtherId, SomeColumn) 
SELECT @SomeId, @SomeOtherId, @SomeValue
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM TableName
  WHERE SomeId = @SomeId AND SomeOtherId = @SomeOtherId
);
```

The `UPDATE` statement will succeed only if there is a row under the conditions you specify, otherwise it will do nothing.
The `INSERT` statement will succeed only if there is not a row under the conditions you specify, otherwise it will do nothing.

Comment: Yup, worked. The semicolon near end in second query is typo, but engine wouldn't let me remove it myself.